# image zoom and transition from collectionView to viewcontroller swift

Tags: swift, collectionview, zooming, xcode8.2

I have a collection view with few images. When I click the image, the image need to zoom and navigate to viewcontroller. For this I used ZoomTransitioning Library. 
https://github.com/WorldDownTown/ZoomTransitioning
 But I am not able to transit the image as given in the gif. My xcode is 8.2.1 and swift 3.0.

I used all the delegates as given in the demo and used pod 'ZoomTransitioning'.

```
 extension ImageCollection {

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! ImageCell
        selectedImageView = cell.imageView
    }
}


// MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

extension ImageCollection {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let space: CGFloat = 8.0
        let length = (collectionView.frame.width - space * 3.0) / 2.0
        return CGSize(width: length, height: length)
    }
}


// MARK: - ZoomTransitionSourceDelegate

extension ImageCollection: ZoomTransitionSourceDelegate {

    func transitionSourceImageView() -> UIImageView {
        return selectedImageView ?? UIImageView()
    }

    func transitionSourceImageViewFrame(forward: Bool) -> CGRect {
        guard let selectedImageView = selectedImageView else { return CGRect.zero }
        return selectedImageView.convert(selectedImageView.bounds, to: view)
    }

    func transitionSourceWillBegin() {
        selectedImageView?.isHidden = true
    }

    func transitionSourceDidEnd() {
        selectedImageView?.isHidden = false
    }

    func transitionSourceDidCancel() {
        selectedImageView?.isHidden = false
    }
```

}

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.